# Audio players in Chrome packaged apps

Tags: javascript, html, audio, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to embed a music player in a Chrome app, and at the moment I'm using the default  tag to embed music, but the problem is that I can't seek the song unless the song has been fully downloaded before playing (I'm streaming it from a file host).

The file host has its own music player, but is made in flash and so it doesn't work in Chrome apps. What should I do?

Comment: Does the seek problem happen when using the audio player in a normal web page, or just when it is in a chrome app?

Comment: I haven't tested that. Do you have any ideas about what could be the reason? I googled a little bit about the issue and from what I read, it seems like it is a server-side issue, and since I don't own the file host I can't exactly fix it. I've just noticed that other players, like the official flash player can seek the music just fine.

Comment: Not sure, but if this is a general web problem you could make the question non-chrome app specific and get more people to look at it. There are probably tags for audio html5 questions.